# Rewrite URL based on item name

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to understand how the rewrite of a file name works. I have a PHP file called `item.php`. If the user selects an item he get for example `item-pencil.php`, `item-book.php` and so on.

I found in the htaccess the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my/path
RewriteRule ^item-.*-(.*).php show_item.php?id=$1
```

Can anyone explain how this works in detail? The file `show_item.php` gets an `id` parameter. And this rule is only valid for the path `/my/path`. `.*` seems to stand for an arbitrary number for characters and `(.*)` means probalby for multiple times. But where does the name `pencil` or `book` come from?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my/path
RewriteRule ^item-.*-(.*).php show_item.php?id=$1
```

Explanation: rewrite rule checks if URL  matches with  given pattern. pattern says url (without host, and `rewritebase` part) should start with "`item-`" followed by anything `.*`, then "-" , after that any character is allowed   `(.*)`, then one character  `.` ,followed by "php" and it can has anything at the end.

So, If you enter "**http://www.yourdomain.com/my/path/item-www-ssss.php.php**"  in your browser, it considers `item-www-ssss.phpphp`  as first parameter for `RewriteRule`. the it applies pattern to it. and it matches the given pattern and given pattern will be substitute by second argument `show_item.php?id=$1`. because `$1` is `ssss`  , so your final result will be `http://www.yourdomain.com/my/path/show_item.php?id=ssss.php`. 
Note `.php` at the end of URL.